# equivalent of an alternating series

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis, analytic-number-theory

Let $d_n=\mathrm{lcm}(1,\cdots,n)$. By the prime number theorem $d_n=e^{n+o(n)}$.
I look for an equivalent of the function $\sum_{n\ge0}(-1)^n\frac{d_n}{n!}t^n$ when $t\to+\infty$. Unfortunately, the series does not satisfy the conditions to apply Leibniz alternating series test.

Any hint or answer would be welcome.

Comment: maybe $\exp(\exp(1).n)$ ?

Comment: What is meant by an "equivalent" of a function?